# Form Submitting Even Though I have a "return false"

Tags: return-value, onsubmit

I have a button that when clicked calls **function1** that calls another **function2**. If function2 meets a condition, it should return false and die there but it continues on, back to function1 the rest of function1 is executed and the form is submitted. I am new to javascript.

```
 <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="function1()" />

 function function1() {
  function2();
  //execute rest of function
 }

 function2() {
 var this;
 var that;
 if(!this || !that) {
 alert("You did not fill out fields on the form under Tab1");
 return false;  //I thought it was supposed to stop here
 }
 }
```

Comment: sorry, actual code for button click is: <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="if(!function1()) return true;" />

Answer (score 1):

In function1 when you call function2, if you want function1 to stop if function 2 returns false then you have to stop it INSIDE function one, like so:

```
function function1() {
  // If function2 returns false, then stop function1
  if (!function2()) return;
  //execute rest of function
 }

 function2() {
  var this;
  var that;
  if(!this || !that) {
   alert("You did not fill out fields on the form under Tab1");
   return false;  //I thought it was supposed to stop here
  }
 }
```

Comment: +1, agree w/ @Jayce444. The form will submit unless you return `false` all the way up. If you just return `false` to function1, you have to handle it from there.

Comment: Jayce444, I tried that, if(!function2()) return; but nothing happened.It never committed the data

Comment: I tried this and this worked: if (function2() == false) { return false; }  But your way seems shorter if I can get it to work

Comment: sorry in my code it should be 'return false' not just 'return'